# Track by property when using observable arrays

Tags: knockout.js

Is it possible to somehow add the track by directive to knockout foreach binding like it is in angular and some other frameworks?

I have a realtime app built using knockout. The data is received using websocket and then rendered using knockout. To simplify the the business logic I want merge the data updates received by websocket to the existing data and then pass that data to knockout altogether. In most cases there will be no new elements.

Will knockout re-render the entire list in this case or will it know that corresponding DOM element already exists? I can't think of any way to detect this without track by directive...

Comment: Please post a repro / code for your situation. I think the repro itself will answer the question you may have.

Answer (score 0):

> Will knockout re-render the entire list in this case or will it know that corresponding DOM element already exists?

So long as you update existing `observable`s, and push new elements into `observableArray`s without changing the entire array, Knockout will only re-render the updated/new elements, yes.

Comment: No I want to regenerate the array and just pass the new value to knockout.

Comment: Ah, I see.  In that case, yes - it will re-render everything.  Ideally you want to update what's there if necessary, not replace it entirely.  You should use knockout in the core of your viewmodel, not just as a device for rendering.